# How to unambiguously trim a string with parser combinators?

Tags: parsing, haskell, parser-combinators, combinators, ambiguous-grammar

My current implementation with `Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP`:

```hs
trim :: ReadP String
trim = do skipSpaces
          content <- some get
          skipSpaces
          eof
          return content
```

The problem is, ambiguous results frequently pop up when run:

```
ghci> readP_to_S trim " hello world "
[("hello world",""),("hello world ","")]
```

I believe I need to specify that the trimmed content will not end with space characters, but I have no idea how to express that apart from this extremely inefficient design:

```hs
trim :: ReadP String
trim = do skipSpaces
          content <- many get
          lastOne <- satisfy (not . isSpace)
          skipSpaces
          eof
          return (content ++ [lastOne])
```

We can have better things, right?

Comment: Why not just trim the *result* of the parser: we can define a `ReadP` that parses the full content, and returns the trimmed, and thus can thus be reused in a larger parser.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I'm afraid I cannot understand that.

Comment: @Futarimiti, `trim = trimString <$> some get`, where `trimString` is a naively implemented trim function like `trimString = dropWhile isSpace . reverse . dropWhile isSpace . reverse`.  Seems kind of silly, only makes sense if you are using `trim` as a component in a larger parser.

Comment: What is the inefficiency that you would like to address?

Comment: @DanielWagner `appending the last character to the string, especially when we got a very very very very long sentence like this `

Comment: @Futarimiti Are you sure that's an issue? I would expect that one-time cost to be very low compared to the other costs of parsing. (It certainly doesn't change the asymptotics.) If you're not sure, then I encourage you to use the simple, easily-readable code until you really need to change.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to do this through parser combinatorics, why not just parse the content and then trim, like:

```
import Data.Char(isSpace)
import Data.List(dropWhileEnd)

trim :: ReadP String
trim = do skipSpaces
          content <- many get
          skipSpaces
          eof
          return (trimData content)

trimStr :: String -> String
trimStr = dropWhileEnd isSpace . dropWhile isSpace
```

The parser can be shortened then to:

```
trim :: ReadP String
trim = trimStr <$> (many get <* eof)
```

We thus first retrieve all characters, and then we return the trimmed string, although the `eof` might not be necessary here.

Answer (score 0):

You could parse a word at a time, then put them back together.

(This does compress any multiple spaces into single ones, if that
matters.)

```
trim :: ReadP String
trim = skipSpaces *> content <* eof
  where
    content = unwords <$> many token
    token = munch1 (not . isSpace) <* skipSpaces
```

But a more direct way is to say that the parse is terminated by a
component which is zero or more spaces *then eof*.  Then we can use `manyTill`, which will attempt to match internal spaces as the terminator, but will fail because those spaces aren't followed by eof.

```
trim :: ReadP String
trim = skipSpaces *> manyTill get (skipSpaces <* eof)
```

(This is potentially slow if you have *long* runs of internal spaces, since after each one the parser will go through the rest to see if an eof is at the end.)

Answer (score 0):

The following parser ought to work:

```
trim :: ReadP String
trim = skipSpaces *> content
  where
    content = do
      spc <- spaces
      ((\w rest -> spc ++ w ++ rest) <$> word <*> content)
        <++ pure ""
    word = munch1 (not .isSpace)
    spaces = munch isSpace
```

The idea is that the `content` parser reads (possibly empty) leading whitespace and then attempts to read a non-empty, non-whitespace `word`.  If such a word is found, the leading whitespace and word are prefixed to additional `content`.  If no word is found, the "leading whitespace" must be trailing whitespace at the end of the input string and is discarded (i.e., `pure ""`).

By itself, `content` will right-trim spaces off the input. By invoking it after `skipSpaces` in the definition of `trim`, we ensure that the result will be left-trimmed as well.

This parser should always return a single alternative `[("trimmed string","")]`, as per the following quick check:

```
import Test.QuickCheck
import Data.List
import Data.Char
import Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP

trim :: ReadP String
trim = skipSpaces *> content
  where
    content = do
      spc <- spaces
      ((\w rest -> spc ++ w ++ rest) <$> word <*> content)
        <++ pure ""
    word = munch1 (not .isSpace)
    spaces = munch isSpace

test_trim :: String -> Bool
test_trim str = readP_to_S trim str == [(dropWhile isSpace (dropWhileEnd isSpace str), "")]

main = quickCheck test_trim
```

Answer (score 0):

If the inefficiency you are worried about stems from `many get` frequently backtracking, you could require each sequence of whitespace to end with a non-whitespace. You can also use the `munch` family to avoid the backtracking introduced by `many (satisfy ...)`.

```
trim :: ReadP String
trim = do skipSpaces
          content <- some $ liftA2 (++)
             (munch isSpace)
             (munch1 (not . isSpace))
          skipSpaces
          eof
          return (concat content)
```